# Using WC_Tax::get_tax_classes() to get all WooCommerce tax-classes

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, tax

I try to get the active tax-classes in Woocommerce in my custom plugin. When I use the `WC_Tax::get_tax_classes()`, I get a empty array.

How does `WC_tax` class work without order details and run by itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WC_Tax::get_tax_classes()` returns an empty array when there is only **the default tax class** set in WooCommerce > Tax *(tab)* settings.

It's used for example in [`wc_get_product_tax_class_options()` function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/includes/wc-product-functions.php#L818-L835) that displays the available tax classes in admin product pages settings:

```
/**
 * Get product tax class options.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @return array
 */
function wc_get_product_tax_class_options() {
    $tax_classes           = WC_Tax::get_tax_classes();
    $tax_class_options     = array();
    $tax_class_options[''] = __( 'Standard', 'woocommerce' );

    if ( ! empty( $tax_classes ) ) {
        foreach ( $tax_classes as $class ) {
            $tax_class_options[ sanitize_title( $class ) ] = $class;
        }
    }
    return $tax_class_options;
}
```

So the default tax class (active tax class) has no entry when using `WC_Tax::get_tax_classes()`.

Then you can use `wc_get_product_tax_class_options()` function to get all WooCommerce tax classes or the code from this function if you want something more custom.

Related: [How to get the available tax rates in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197414/how-to-get-the-available-tax-rates-in-woocommerce/66197864#66197864)

Comment: Thanks! That helps me a lot! Now, i get the available classes :-) But how show the rates and names?

Comment: Thanks! I posted a new question in addition to this :-) 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197414/get-available-tax-rates-from-woocommerce-with)